# Problems with wordpress slider -> Cyclone2

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a question about wordpress slider plugin Cyclone2.

Problem is that when I upload and add an image to slider, it outputs incorrect *src* url for img tag on site page, like adding slider width and height to image url..

Ex. I upload image `Champagne-All-Bottles.jpg`.
In admin panel image loads successfuly: `/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Champagne-All-Bottles.jpg`
but on site page it adds a `width` and `height` to `img` url like: `/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Champagne-All-Bottles-1200x400.jpg`

HTML admin panel(correct):

[image]

HTML output on site page(incorrect url):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Resize Images?

-No, shut up!

@TotalCare, thank you for your help :)

[image: no_resize]

Answer (score 0):

This plugin probaly makes an 1200*400 picture copy of the one you are giving because somewhere in the settings you say that the slider should be 1200*400 pixels. So the plugin is transforming your picture to the dimensions of the slider. Is there somewhere in the settings of the plugin something where you can adjust the dimensions?

A lot of WordPress plugins do this, and even WordPress itself is doing this. Making different dimension copies of images you upload.

EDIT: I searched the plugin you are talking about and in I think in basic settings the "width" and "height" are there so you can change the dimensions. But one thing, all images uploaded will get the same dimensions, thats how this (and a lot of other) WordPress plugin works.

Note: if you set "Width Management" to fixed, the plugin probably stops resizing your image, can you give it a try?

Comment: I don't understand why does it add `URL-$height+$height.$ext` to url, if it should be adding like this `<img src="CORRECT_URL" width="$width" height="$height" />`

Comment: I tried to set `width management` to fixed, but nothing changes

Comment: That is the way WordPress deals with other dimensions of the same image, the plugins people build do the same. Make a copy of the original with the dimensions in the new URL. The reason they put it in the URL is because they always make a copy of it so that you could use the original another time without having to upload it again. So it doesn't resize the image with HTML but it makes a resized copy of the image.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I'm not sure what you want to change here.

Comment: Okay, but where is a resized copy of image? - I think it doesn't exist as it doesn't load.

Comment: Could you give me the URL of your website so I could take a look? Edit: ah, I missed the 'localhost' part I guess... Could you check your ./uploads/2015/12 directory if there is a copy in there? If you set Width Management to fixed, add the same image again and publish, what happens on the website?